# Is there any way to make a package of all git submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

My project has a bunch of git submodules, and every time I clone my project, it takes a long time to clone all submodules.

Is there any way to make all submodules as a package, so maybe I can just unzip them, pull new commits, instead of clone them all?

I've tried just packing the submodule directories together in previous git version, and it works fine due to the git root of submodules are right in the path/to/submodule/.git, but recently, I found that they put the submodule git root centralized in .git/modules/path/to/submodule/.git, so this way is not working now.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

A git working-tree is intended to be self-contained; you should be able to just copy your whole tree, submodules and all, and place it wherever it needs to go.

You say "*every time I clone my project...*" - can you explain the workflow you're using that needs you to clone your project a large number of times?

Comment: Thanks for yout answer, actually it may not be called as a "project".
I'm hosting my dotfiles including vim setting and plugins on github as described [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/synchronizing-plugins-with-git-submodules-and-pathogen/).
So I will clone it every time when I have a new linux account.

Comment: And also what you said "_you should be able to just copy your whole tree, submodules and all, and place it wherever it needs to go._" is not working, because all my path/to/submodules/.git files are containing something like "**gitdir: /path/to/cloned/.git/modules/path/to/submodule**" as you see, they are in absolutely path, so I can't move it to another path, or it will broken.